# Receiving has literal was incomplete for below query

Tags: azure, powershell

```
$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription

 

$result = foreach ($vsub in $subscriptions){
    Select-AzSubscription $vsub.SubscriptionID

 


    Write-Host
    Write-Host "Working on $($vsub.Name)"
    Write-Host

 


    foreach($VM in (Get-AzVM)){
       # $Tier = (Get-AzResource -ResourceId $webapp.ServerFarmId).Sku.Tier
       # $Plan = Get-AzAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName $webapp.ResourceGroup

 

 

        # output the object so it gets collected in $result
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            TenantId         = $vsub.TenantId
            SubscriptionName = $vsub.Name
            VMName       = $VM.Name
            ResourceGroup    = $VM.ResourceGroup

 

           # Hostname         = $webapp.DefaultHostName
            #PricingTier      = $Tier
            #SKU              = @($Plan.Sku.Size) -join ','
            #AppServiceName   = @($Plan.Name) -join ','
            Status           = $VM.PowerState
            Location        = $VM.Location
            Size            = $VM.HardwareProfile.VmSize
            Application_Name= $VM.Tags.Application_Name
            Application_Owner= $VM.Tags.Application_Owner
            Business_Owner = $VM.Tags.Business_Owner
            Cost_Code = $VM.Tags.Cost_Code
            Created_Date = $VM.Tags.Created_Date
            Environment_Name = $VM.Tags.Environment_Name
            ENVIRONMENT_NAME = $VM.Tags.ENVIRONMENT_NAME
            #AppType         = $webapp.Kind
        #SubscriptionID   = $vsub.SubscriptionID
        }
    }
}

 


# sort unique and export the file
$result | Sort-Object * -Unique | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Desktop\Scripts\vm_inventory.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

I am trying to run this query to get the details of the VM but I am receiving the hash literal is incomplete for PSCustomObject, as per my knowledge all the brackets are proper but don't know why I am receiving the error. Request to please help me on the same.

Comment: Remove the commented lines inside the PSCustomObject

Comment: Better yet, remove the **blank** lines in the PsCustomObject. Howetver, I think the main problem is that you repeat item `ENVIRONMENT_NAME`

Comment: Tried removing but its same

Comment: @Theo tried as per the suggestion its still the same

Comment: Did you remove entry `ENVIRONMENT_NAME`? PowerShell is case-independant, so that is the same as `Environment_Name`

Comment: @Theo Yes, I have removed ENVIRONMENT_NAME

Comment: .. weird.. I don't see what else is wrong then. We are obviously overlooking something. Can you do trial and error by commenting out entries to find the one that causes the error?

Comment: The [PsCustomObject] definition itself is correct (except for the duplicate `ENVIRONMENT_NAME` key) . The empty or commented out lines do not matter. Therefore, I can only assume one of the values causes this problem.